# How can the "anti-correlation" between these two curves be shown?

Tags: probability, correlation, data-visualization, modeling

I'm looking at data defined on a given feature with respect to two measures. Whilst both measures are defined on the same domain, both measures are defined on different ranges, so, with a view to displaying both curves on the same plot, they have been normalized (to sum to one across the support like a probability density function).

[image: Two measures defined on same feature.]

From the visualization, there can be observed an "alternating peaks" pattern between both measures. This is interesting because theory hypothesizes that the measure represented by the blue curve has an inhibitory or silencing effect on the measure represented by the red curve.

[image: Scatter Plot of Curve Values]

In some respects these alternating peaks can be considered to be anti-correlated with one another; however, the anti-correlation in this scatter does not look particularly strong.
Similarly, a regression model doesn't look particularly appropriate in this case either as the scatter plot demonstrates. The relationship doesn't really seem to be apparent.

Is there a better way to capture and quantify the alternating peaks pattern present between the two measures in the data?

**Edit**:

As mentioned in the comments, the following table is sample data constructed to have similar properties to the original data over a shorter domain.

```
             Coordinate Measure1 (Blue Curve) Measure2 (Red Curve)
 1           1            0.01190476           0.01369863
 2           2            0.01190476           0.01369863
 3           3            0.01190476           0.01369863
 4           4            0.02380952           0.02739726
 5           5            0.15476190           0.01369863
 6           6            0.15476190           0.02739726
 7           7            0.11904762           0.05479452
 8           8            0.00000000           0.08219178
 9           9            0.00000000           0.10958904
 10         10            0.00000000           0.10958904
 11         11            0.00000000           0.10958904
 12         12            0.00000000           0.10958904
 13         13            0.00000000           0.10958904
 14         14            0.03571429           0.06849315
 15         15            0.15476190           0.04109589
 16         16            0.14285714           0.02739726
 17         17            0.15476190           0.02739726
 18         18            0.02380952           0.02739726
 19         19            0.00000000           0.01369863
 20         20            0.00000000           0.00000000
```

Comment: The chance of observing *this* scenario by chance is zero.

Comment: It will be useful if you post some sample data here.

Comment: @NeilG Can you elaborate on why this is?

Comment: @rnso I've made some edits to my original post. The original data is defined across 76 coordinates for each measure, so I've constructed sample data across 20 coordinates such that it has more or less the same properties.

Comment: Your statement "Obviously, the curves are neither linear nor monotonic, so it seems that both Pearson and Spearman correlations are inappropriate in this case" is puzzling, because neither measure of correlation has anything at all to do with the *sequences* of the data, which is what the apparent linearity or monotonicity of the curves refers to. Resolving this misconception may answer your question.

Comment: @whuber I'm probably missing the point of your comment, but it seems to me that the visual representation of the correlation is given by the scatter above. In other words, the extent to which the first point of Measure1 is correlated with the first point of Measure2, the second of Measure1 correlated with the second of Measure2, and so on. The scatter suggests weak anti-correlation. This is confirmed by the returned values of -0.36 and -0.32 for Pearson and Spearman methods respectively (sample data). This doesn't characterise the apparent strong anti-correlation present in the density plot.

Comment: @whuber Upon having a look at the question again, I believe it my wording may have been ambiguous. With a view to achieving clarity, I have made sufficient changes to the wording. Perhaps this makes things a little clearer; perhaps not.

Comment: Correlation is a measure of association: it characterizes the scatterplot of $(x_i,y_i)$. Your red and blue lines instead trace out scatterplots of $(i,x_i)$ and $(i,y_i)$, although the index $i$ is labeled "$x$". You haven't shown anything that is called or even looks like a "density plot," nor have you exhibited anything that looks like "strong anti-correlation," so I don't know to what you are referring there.

Comment: @whuber  1. Surely the $(i,x_{i})$ and $(i,y_{i})$ are represented by the **first** plot encountered - the red and blue lines don't constitute a scatter, insofar as they both measures trace out *lines* - i.e. geom_line() in ggplot parlance. I'm referring to the **second** plot - i.e. geom_point() in ggplot parlance. Why doesn't the second plot represent the correlation between Blue Curve and Red Curve?

Comment: @whuber 2. In the first plot, both measures (red and blue curves) are normalized to sum to one, where each individual value, $X$, has $f(X) \geq  0$ across the support in both measures - technically, they should be represented by histograms as they are both discrete-valued. Why can't both curves be interpreted as densities?

Comment: @whuber  3. By anti-correlation, I simply meant that, for the most part, the red curve tends to high values where the blue curve has low values and vice versa - the quotation marks around the first use of "anti-correlation" in this context was supposed to suggest an abuse of terminology. Do you agree that the above property is observable or am I delusional in this instance?

Comment: The scatter plot is less convincing than the top  (by-position) plot because a. The near-zeros on the edges don't agree with the theory b. It misses the fact that the inhibitory effect seems to have some spatial influence. Maybe a scatter plot with a smoothed version of the curves might be more instructive.

Comment: @KishKash You're right - the near-zeros are definitely in conflict with the theory. I was hoping that the replies to the question would have more robust solutions (when compared with the basic correlation approaches that I discussed) that would preserve the apparent effect from the first plot. I had already considered removing the "edges" of the data to correct for the near-zeros, but this seemed a little "hack-y". Smoothing is certainly something that I'll look at. Cheers!

Comment: If you trim the tails, you can regress "Red - Blue" against "$X$" and "$X^2$" to demonstrate and test that the difference is large (positive) at the ends and large (negative) in the middle. This is a legitimate use case for a one-sided t test -- rare in the wild!

Comment: The scatterplot to directly compare the two measurements is *far* more insightful then attempting to estimate correlation from two parallel plots of the measurements against their indices. In that sense yes, the appearance of "strong anti-correlation" is somewhat of a delusion in this case. We cannot speak to "robustness" because you have provided no information even suggesting the values with extreme indices (at the right and left of your plots) might be considered differently than the other values: you have asked about "correlation" and we have responded accordingly.

Comment: @whuber but there's clearly a pattern of alternating peaks and troughs. maybe the OP should really be asking "what is this pattern, and is it quantifiable?"

Comment: @user9171 Neil G is being coy. The probability of observing any particular event with a continuous distribution is infinitesimally small, which means it's zero. You could define a range of "equivalent" scenarios and then define a probability of observing a scenario in that range, but then the probability will depend entirely on the size of the range. This issue is one of the reasons people are uncomfortable with null hypothesis testing

Comment: @ssde (re "alternating peaks and troughs"): Agreed. Questions fare better here when they are couched in terms of what the OP really needs to know rather than in terms of some abstract metaphor or unexplained mathematical model.

Comment: Perhaps the question is ill-posed to the extent that the desired answer will perhaps remain elusive. I had hoped that the final question, "In light of the above, does anybody have any suggestions as to which methods adequately demonstrate the relationship between both measures?" would suggest that I was hoping for a method to illustrate the "alternating peaks", better than the above. Instead of requesting a method, I figured I'd walk through the problem and some sub-par solutions. Thanks to everybody for your suggestions and assistance in reformatting the question in more intelligible ways.

Comment: Sorry user9171 for not writing more, but I was daunted by the long discussion.   All I meant was that you should reword your desire for "how likely we are to observe this scenario by chance" to "how likely we are to observe a scenario as (or more) 'anti-correlated' as this one by chance"  I don't like p-values, but that's usually how they work.  You still need a measure of anti-correlation.  This might be naïve, but what's wrong with the negative correlation?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Thank you. I suspected that this was Neil G's intention. Even though I feel that glib responses are typically less helpful, I've found it better ignore tone. In the event of Neil G's response, I had planned to assert that the support is discrete-valued, so, in theory, there is no necessity for the probability of observing the scenario by chance to be zero.

Comment: @NeilG Thank you for your response. I appreciate your reticence to delve into that discussion. It was my fault for not declaring, in the first instance, that the support was discrete-valued, and, hence, that the probability of observing the above result by chance was not necessarily zero - as in my previous comment. However, I accept your point that, specifically, I was interested in observations *at least as extreme*. I plan to be more careful next time.

Comment: @ssdecontrol RE regressing "Red - Blue" against  $X, \ldots$: in theory, assume the "Blue" measure consists of small values relative the "Red" measure and that "Red" depends on $X$ quadratically. In this case, subtracting the "Blue" effect from the "Red" effect would simply lead to small perturbations of the "Red" effect; here, regressing "Red - Blue" on $X, \ldots$ would amount to little more than "Red" on $X, \ldots$ (i.e. results would be similar regardless of whether "Blue" was included). As such, the analysis doesn't necessarily show that curves are alternating. Is this correct?

Comment: @user9171 use the rescaled measures from the graphic

Comment: @ssdecontrol That's what I figured would be best, but rescaling doesn't seem to solve all problems. Say the "Blue" effect was constant across all coordinates, whilst the "Red" effect remained as it currently is. Regressing "Red - Blue" against $X,\ldots$ for the hypothetical constant "Blue" effect and for the actual "Blue" effect yields the same properties (in terms of the sign of the difference), it's just the case that it's more extreme (in terms of magnitude) in the real situation than in the hypothetical situation.

Comment: @ssdecontrol This encouraged me to consider perhaps regressing "Red" on $X,\ldots$ **and** "Red-Blue" on $X,\ldots$ and setting up some sort of contrast comparison - this would allow the difference in magnitude to suggest that there was greater alternation in the peaks of the curves encapsulated by the larger magnitude in difference. Of course, in this instance, the data would have to be scaled (centred and normalized as opposed to simply normalized) to facilitate negative values for the "Red" on $X,\ldots$ model (otherwise parameter estimates would be invariably positive).

Answer (score 6):

One curve almost looks like the derivative of the other and sometimes such pairs of curves are plotted against each other with curved connections. For instance, for plotting velocity versus acceleration to see cycles better. Here is red versus blue for your toy data:

[image]

Arrows and annotations are sometimes added. I don't know what these kinds of plots are properly called. I've heard "phase-plane" diagrams but that term includes a lot of other kinds of plots, too.

The data points are connected in this case. With more and noisier data, you'd probably want some kind of interpolated curve that just goes near each point.

Update: In case it doesn't go without saying, I'm not sure what you mean by "anti-correlation". I'm thinking you want to show a relationship between two curves that is not functional in the usual sense. For the chart I've shown, you can think of it as parametric plot in that each variable (blue and red) is a function of a parameter ("Coordinate" in your table).

For comparison, here's another application of this kind of diagram from a [NYT graphic on gas prices](http://www.nytimes.com/imagepages/2010/05/02/business/02metrics.html?action=click&contentCollection=Business%20Day&module=RelatedCoverage&region=Marginalia&pgtype=article).

[image]

Comment: Alberto Cairo calls these types of charts [connected scatterplots](http://www.thefunctionalart.com/2012/09/in-praise-of-connected-scatter-plots.html).

Comment: Thanks @AndyW. Now that you mention it, I see that's what it's called on Jon Schwabish's Graphic Continuum poster. I guess there could be different names for the curved specialization.

Comment: @xan Thanks for your answer. I really like the effect of illustrating the cycles. However, it's more visualization-based inference, which, while undoubtedly informative, doesn't seem to allow for quantification. Does it?

Comment: Right @user9171. I was assuming a different meaning of "show" :)

Comment: @xan That's my fault for not being clearer. Although, I really like the plot! Thanks! :)

Comment: (+1) This is a very good answer. It allows for quantification. A natural way is to compute the correlation coefficient. The visualization shows that correlation is an incomplete description of the behavior, which evidently differs from some random scatter of points around a linear function. Where to go from there requires a probabilistic model of the data behavior. Because such a model is lacking and cannot be inferred (due to an incomplete and vague description of the data-generation process), answers in this thread cannot go much beyond such illustrations.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input. I can provide more information on the data-generating process, of course. What would you like to know?

Comment: The best thing would be to explain, in your own (non-statistical) terminology, what the *raw* data represent, how you have collected them, and your theory concerning their relationship. Some of your previous comments suggest you are thinking of these as time series $x$ and $y$ and that after they commence $x$ might influence $y$, perhaps with some lag in time--but those are guesses on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The plot of one measure against the other (@xan's answer) is a good idea, except that I don't think it makes sense to join the points in this way. It only makes sense if the order of observations is really important. My understanding is that the fact that they're anti-correlated doesn't have anything to do with their ordering.

So you should plot them one against the other, to get a cloud of points. Measure the correlation using a metric like Pearson's correlation coefficient, and you will presumably get a negative value like -0.5 or so.

Then, you can show that this is statistically significant by a randomization test:

you have the values:

`blue0, blue1, ... , bluen` 
and 
`red0, red1, ... redn`

Saying that the anti-correlation you observe is significant and is unlikely to happen by chance basically means that if instead of matching `bluek` to `redk` for all `k`, you match them randomly, then it is very unlikely that the resulting dataset will display this level of correlation.

So you can prove this by generating many random permutations of the red data, and calculating the correlation of the permuted red values with the original blue.

Sort the correlation values obtained, and see how extreme the true correlation is. Is it in the top 1%? 0.1%? This gives you an estimate of how unlikely it is to happen by chance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, initially, I had intended to implement a scheme like the one you suggested, but, unfortunately, the anti-correlation isn't really manifest in the results. Basically, the correlation amounts to approximately -0.3, so the approach doesn't really work. To see why this is, have a look at the second figure provided in my original question.

Comment: @user9171 right, I had missed that plot. I would say although -0.3 is not a very high value in absolute (-0.99 would be nicer), statistically it's probably very meaningful (if you have lots of data points). But -0.3 may be enough to argue that one measure has a silencing effect over the other.  So maybe you should extract the more meaningful data points (not "those that prove your preferred point", but "those that have an important interpretation in the domain"), and see if those are more correlated.

Comment: For example, when both measurements are 0, does it make sense to say they are correlated/anti-correlated? maybe it's only meaningful if one is non-zero. Also maybe the ordering *is* meaningful, and they tend to *vary* in opposite directions, so you can see if the derivatives of the measurements are anti-correlated...